# React generate dropdown items depending on array

Tags: reactjs, loops

iam trying to generate some dropdownitems via an array, but only catch errors.

This was working before:

```
    const [id, setId] = useState(1);

    const datadisplay = [
        ['headline 1','name1','text1'],
        ['headline 2','name2','text2'],
        ['headline 3','name3','text3'],];
```

_

```
                    <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                        setId(1)
                    }}>{datadisplay[0][0]}</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                        setId(2)
                    }}>{datadisplay[1][0]}</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                        setId(3)
                    }}>{datadisplay[2][0]}</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                        setId(4)
                    }}>{datadisplay[3][0]}</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                        setId(5)
                    }}>{datadisplay[4][0]}</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                        setId(6)
                    }}>{datadisplay[5][0]}</Dropdown.Item>
```

But iam trying to make it a oneliner. Maybe i missunderstood for loops in react but it seems correct:

Array was changed to:

```
const datadisplay = [
    [{id:1,headline:'headline 1',name:'name1',text:'text1'}],
    [{id:2,headline:'headline 2',name:'name2',text:'text2'}],
    [{id:3,headline:'headline 3',name:'name3',text:'text3'}],];
```

_

```
  {datadisplay.map(item=> (<Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {setId(item.id)}}>{item.headline}</Dropdown.Item>))}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it will works if you change the `datadisplay` object.
Your object should be an `Array` of `Object` like `= [{},{},{}]`.

```js
const datadisplay = [
    {
      id:1,
      headline:'headline 1',
      name:'name1',
      text:'text1'
    },
    {
      id:2,
      headline:'headline 2',
      name:'name2',text:'text2'
    },
    {
      id:3,
      headline:'headline 3',
      name:'name3',
      text:'text3'
    },
];
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: Would if i could, but sadly i am restricted.